# Is using an invisible activity a bad practice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentservice, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm working with several applications.
To log in we uses Oauth2 with customtabs using chrome.

The "mother" application performs a login then send an intent to every application to say "perform login a preload your data in background"

From there each application opens a customtab and close it, then do its other tasks in background.

yes I know, this is ugly, 6 customtabs are being opened and closed, but it is what was asked, no other solution is wanted.

**To do that I made an activity without UI.**

The activity receive the intent, launch the customtabs, retrieve the authorisation_code, get the tokens, then call a service to preload data and close itself (the invisible activity close itself)

Is that bad?

I did this because it's impossible to add an intent filter to an intent service, and my chrome customtabs send a intent when it's done. so only an activity can grab it.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are the 6 custom chrome tabs for? I don't understand why you need to open 6 of them?

Comment: to get the authorisation code you need to perform a login on a url.
If the user has already logged in in any application then the webpage will just flash 1 seconds and give you the authorisation code (because there is a cookie in the customtab).


each application has to open the custom chrome tabs because it is the only way for an application to get the authorisation code.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I think it's a very bad practice to have an invisible UI. There should be something on the screen to indicate what is happening. How can you have an invisible UI with a chrome custom tab?

Comment: well by no UI I mean no App UI, the activity does not link to any XML in its onCreate method, the only thing you see is a customtab

Comment: Oh okay, I would say that is fine as long as there is a cancel options if the user no longer wants to perform the login.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are developing a multiflavored app.

It's perfectly fine to use a deeplink activity to receive the intent to retrieve the code
and finish it directly in oncreate